# Implementing skeletal animation and GPU skinning (DOOM MD5)

Tags: c++, opengl, animation, glsl, skeletal-animation

**DISCLAIMER**
This question has been completely rewritten to narrow the scope of the question in light of previous suggestions and answers, but the same problem still persists.

Currently I'm trying to implement skeletal animation (GPU skinning) in my project.

So far I have achieved single joint translation and rotation, and multi-jointed translation. The problem arises when I try to rotate a multi-jointed skeleton.

At the moment I'm following quite a few sources in trying to implement skeletal animation. [The MD5 spec](http://tfc.duke.free.fr/coding/md5-specs-en.html), [a blog post](http://petercappetto.com/skeletal-animation-project/) with [source code](https://github.com/pcapp/bones) and I've also seen [many](http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/www/tutorial38/tutorial38.html) [other](http://3dgep.com/?p=1053) [tutorials](http://3dgep.com/?p=1356).

Currently when I try and load the popular "Bob Lamp" model, I get this result.
[image: Boblmap implementation]

Some information about my implementation:

- My maths is ordered with "vector to the left"
- The vectors and rotations of animation frames are being converted into matrices
- I pre-multiply the inverse bind pose and pose matrices

Here is my shader code.

```
#version 330 core

smooth out vec2 vVaryingTexCoords;
smooth out vec3 vVaryingNormals;
smooth out vec4 vWeightColor;

uniform mat4 MV;
uniform mat4 MVP;
uniform mat4 Pallete[55];

layout(location = 0) in vec3 vPos;
layout(location = 1) in vec2 vTexCoords;
layout(location = 2) in vec3 vNormals;
layout(location = 3) in int vSkeleton[4];
layout(location = 4) in vec3 vWeight;

void main()
{
    vec4 wpos2 = vec4(0.0);
    vec4 norm2 = vec4(0.0);
    vec4 wpos = vec4(vPos, 1.0);
    vec4 norm = vec4(vNormals, 0.0);
    vec4 weight = vec4(vWeight, (1.0f-(vWeight[0] + vWeight[1] + vWeight[2])));

    mat4 BoneTransform = mat4(0.0);
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        float fW = weight[i];

        if(fW > 0) {
            int jI = vSkeleton[i];
            vec4 tmpPos = wpos * (Pallete[jI]);
            wpos2 += fW * tmpPos;
        }
    }

    wpos2 /= wpos2.w;

    vWeightColor = weight;
    vVaryingTexCoords = vTexCoords;
    vVaryingNormals = normalize(vec3(vec4(vNormals, 0.0) * MV));
    gl_Position = wpos2 * MVP;
}
```

Another peculiar thing to mention is that multi-jointed animation works when the vertices are inline with the bones. As soon as the vertices move away from the bones, they deform incorrectly.

**UPDATE**
In response to @MickLH

My shader code now has `wpos2 /= wpos2.w` after the for loop. This is the result.
[image: new shader code]

Comment: I've had similar problems when implementing a .ms3d loader.
Try simplifying things as much as you can, for example you could remove vertex weights from the equation, also I would be experimenting with a 3D object as it might give you a better understanding of whats going wrong.

Also I believe your line `BoneTransform += ...` should be `BoneTransform *= ...`.

Comment: I checked my old source codes, and found out that my recommendation is still not good and it should be written as
`BoneTransform = (...) * BoneTransform;`

Comment: @akaltar I've already tried simplifying things, the current code now can do single bone rotation and translation plus multijointed translation, I've just been stuck on getting the multijointed rotation correctly.

I'll try the code you suggested.

Comment: @akaltar could you possibly show me your're code please?

Comment: Its not exactly my code, but an official implementation(based on which I made my own). And also its not about md5, but ms3d(skeleton animation's base seems the same tough). But here's it anyways: [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nk17hqt3zz49jpi/MsViewer.rar)

Comment: @akaltar In your code, you have a line that says `R_ConcatTransforms (m_pBones[nParentBone].mAbsolute, m_pBones[i].mRelative, m_pBones[i].mAbsolute);`
I see you have a relative and absolute, what do these mean?

Comment: I don't think it's the issue, but unless you are sure your weight[] vectors add up to 1.0, you probably want wpos2/=wpos2.w; at the end of your loop.

Comment: Please do not massively re-write your question after answer have been posted, it invalidates the posted answers. It's better to post a new question in that case (this is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum).

Comment: @MickLH doing the `wpos2 /= wpos2.w` fixed some of the verts messing up, like the ones going upwards. There are still some verts that are incorrectly skinned, such as the arms.

Comment: post a new picture please, I am suspicious that you are just not satisfied with the simple linear blending, if the linear blending works it's time to get into the more complex math :)

Comment: @MickLH Updated the question.

Comment: I don't understand what you are doing "vec4 weight = vec4(vWeight, (1.0f-(vWeight[0] + vWeight[1] + vWeight[2])));" for, can you just come on chat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your layout is illegal, vSkeleton[4] needs 4 indices since it is a 4-part array.

```
layout(location = 3) in int vSkeleton[4];
layout(location = 4) in vec3 vWeight;
```

should be:

```
layout(location = 3) in int vSkeleton[4];
layout(location = 7) in vec3 vWeight;
```

or better yet you should use [glGetUniformLocation](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGetUniformLocation.xml) and let the GLSL compiler assign them for your:

```
in int vSkeleton[4];
in vec3 vWeight;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this will solve your problem, but at least I can point some lines in your code, that I don't belive are correct.

First of all, you need to decide how you're going to multiply your matrices and vectors, i.e. are you going to use the left-side or right-side convention. In your shader code you have this line:

```
wpos = BoneTransform * wpos;
```

which suggests "vectors on the right", but then you have this:

```
gl_Position = wpos * MVP;
```

so it simply does not match. So, you either need to change the first on or the second one. But does it matter which one? Since you're calling your matrix `MVP` I will assume that this is equal to

```
ModelViewMatrix * ProjectionMatrix
```

and in that case you should probably use the "vectors on the left" convention. It's not very common but that's totally fine to me. So it may look like the only thing you need to fix is `wpos = wpos * BoneTransform`. Indeed, the formula

```
BoneTransform += (invBindPose[vSkeleton[i]] * Pallete[vSkeleton[i]]) * weight[i];
```

is good enough for left-side vector multiplication,
at least if the `Pallete` matrices are computed the right way,
but are they?

In fact, this is determined by the `MD5mech` file format itself. I've look throught their [documentation](http://tfc.duke.free.fr/coding/md5-specs-en.html) but I'm not entirely sure which convention they're actually using. BTW, because of this ambiguity, it's always better to use `4x4` matrices than quaternion + vector pair. In your situation this is a matter of checking wheter you should use `pqi` instead of `pq` in the formula

```
Math3::quat::RotateVector3(rpos, pq, jv);
```

or not. Also another line

```
Math3::quat nq = pq * jq;
```

could be `nq = jq * pq` as well, so in fact you have at most 4 cases to check. Probably the easiest way to go is to expermient, but I would encourage you to look in the source code of the `Math3` library to determine if their `RotateVector3` routine behaves as described in the `MD5mesh` docs.

Also have in mind that there are at least two conventions to store quaternions in memory, which differ in the order of quaternion's coordinates. The natural one is `w,x,y,z` but I've observed that some engines/libraries tends to place the `w` coordinate at the end of the sequence. That is usually fine, unless you're forced to convert from `vec4` to quaternion or vice-versa. From my experiance it can be a real pain to look for errors of this type, so be carefull with that.

@akaltar Please note, that `*=` is used for composing transformations. Here we only want to compute a baricentric combination of some affine transformations, so in the formula for `BoneTransform` the use of `+=` is totally fine.

Comment: I have updated my question to respond to your points.

Comment: Please try using (in shader code) the transposition of the matrices returned by `GetMatrix` routine, while keeping the order of multiplication `wpos = wpos * BoneTransform`.

Comment: Okay so trying this I changed `BoneTransform += (invBindPose[vSkeleton[i]] * Pallete[vSkeleton[i]]) * weight[i];` to `BoneTransform += (transpose(invBindPose[vSkeleton[i]]) * transpose(Pallete[vSkeleton[i]])) * weight[i];`. The result is a deformation which looks like the central image in the first set of images I posted in this question.

Comment: @Soapy I saw that you're using `Parent.Pos` and `Parent.Translation` in your code. What's the difference between these tow guys?

Comment: There is none, they both the same thing. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** `normalize(weight);` is wrong as it does not make the components add up to one, it makes the length of the vector one which is not what you want. But as you do not use it's return value this line doesn't do anything. This line is probably not required from what I understand of your setup.

**2.** `BoneTransform +=` makes no sense. Adding matrixes together does not concatenate the transforms, you need to multiply them. But this isn't correct for another reason:

You may not apply bone weights to the transformations, you have to apply them to the transformed vertex:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    if(vSkeleton[i] != -1) {
        if(i == 0) {
            BoneTransform = ((invBindPose[vSkeleton[i]] * Pallete[vSkeleton[i]]) * weight[i]);
            // BoneTransform = ((Pallete[vSkeleton[i]] * invBindPose[vSkeleton[i]]) * weight[i]);
        } else {
            BoneTransform += ((invBindPose[vSkeleton[i]] * Pallete[vSkeleton[i]]) * weight[i]);
            // BoneTransform += ((Pallete[vSkeleton[i]] * invBindPose[vSkeleton[i]]) * weight[i]);
        }
    }
}

wpos = BoneTransform * wpos;
```

Has to look more like this:

```
wpos = 0.0;
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) 
{
    if(vSkeleton[i] != -1) 
    {
        BoneTransform = invBindPose[vSkeleton[i]] * Pallete[vSkeleton[i]];
        wpos += ( BoneTransform * vec4(vPos, 1.0) ) * weight[i];
    }
}
```

This is one reason why hlsl's mul function is better thant glsl's * operator. You may not switch around the operands when doing (matrix * vector) * scalar.

I'm not sure if I caught all the problems. There could still be problems on the cpu side and how your pass parameters. Let me know how it goes

**3.** PERFORMANCE: You should remove the binding pose from the bone transformation on the cpu. This has to be done for each vertex on the gpu and only once for each bone when done on the cpu.

Comment: I have updated my question to respond to your points.

Comment: I'm pretty sure += is wrong here as it is applied to the transformation not to the transformed vertex as I did it in my proposal. The transformations itself can not simply get scaled and summed together, think about what happens when scaling a rotation matrix. Summing the weighted resulting vertices using += is a barycentric combination that results in the final vertex.

Comment: I suggest you write a little test where you transform the bone positions and rotations on the cpu and render helper objects to figure out where the problem lies.